# hard/soft edges set normal angle

Tags: edges

how can I set se normal angle of an edge, to make it soft, hard or something inbetween?? (without beveling, withou more geometry)

I do it in maya selecting the edge ...menu/mesh display/set normal angle...

or just selecting ...menu/mesh display/hard edge

[image]
[image]

Comment: You can smoothen selected geometry with `W` > *Smooth* or scale it along normals with `Alt`+`S` to make it located under harder / softer angle. I don't *think* there's the same operator in Blender.

Comment: You also have an autosmooth option and the ability to mark edges sharp

Answer (score 3):

This is an old question, but I figured out the correct answer after having no luck searching for it online.

The Blender equivalent to Maya's Set Normal Angle is in *Object Data Properties > Normals > Auto Smooth*.  You check Auto Smooth on, and set a percentage value.

However, it will most likely do nothing.  I found there's possibly 3 other settings that need to be set for it to work right.

1. *Object Data Properties > Geometry Data > Clear Custom Split Normals Data*.  This is only necessary if it says Clear Custom Split Normals Data, rather than Add Custom Split Normals Data.
2. In *Object Mode*, <kbd>Right Click</kbd> the object and select *Shade Smooth*.
3. Go into *Edit Mode*, select all faces (hit <kbd>A</kbd>), go to *Edge > Clear Sharp*.

If all 3 are set correctly, then the *AutoSmooth* should do what you want.

Answer (score 2):

Select the object, context menu and click *Shade smooth*, then on edges, you select *Mark sharp*  or *Clear sharp* as you need.

You can smoothen selected geometry with <kbd>W</kbd>  > *Smooth* or scale it along normals with <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>S</kbd>  to make it located under harder / softer angle. That's adding a "smooth mesh" in Maya, adds twice the geometry per iteration and it's not related.

I don't think there's the same operator in Blender, it is, like most of the Blender equivalent its just named in a different way.

Go into edit mode and hit <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>B</kbd> and drag the cursor until you have the desired amount. no, that's beveling, maya ahs athe same concept in *Mesh tools, bevel* again, adds geometry, totally unrelated.

Go to the modifier tab and click:
*Add Modifier > Generate > Bevel* again, adds a bevel, which changes geometry and destroy uvs, not related to question.

There is the crease tool, which allows you to sharpen the edges by whatever amount you want, and doesn't add more mesh to do it, like the bevel tool does. Just select the edge(s) and press <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>E</kbd> , then pull the string you see attached to the mouse until the edges are as sharp as you want them. They will turn pinkish/purple as the crease gets sharper. You can adjust this at any time by pressing Shift-E again and relaxing the string with the mouse.

Nope, that's the crease tool, Maya has the same tool also named crease, and it's nothing like the guy asked.

What has turned me away from Blender has been the answers everywhere. "Not possible" actually means "I don't know how, so ill just say it doesn't exist".

A friend of mine who said was a Blender expert always told me of things that weren't possible to do in Blender, and it turns out not only they exist, but are easier to do that in other software.

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways of beveling in Blender.

Method One:
Go into edit mode and hit 'shift b' and drag the cursor until you have the desired amount. This will add more geometry though.

Method two:Go to the modifier tab and click:
 *add modifier > generate > bevel* 
This will not add more geometry unless if you select 'apply'.

Comment: ctrl+B for the beveling (or is it OS dependent ?)

Comment: Yes, I believe it would be 'cmd' on a Mac OS.

Answer (score 0):

There is the crease tool, which allows you to sharpen the edges by whatever amount you want, and doesn't add more mesh to do it, like the bevel tool does. Just select the edge(s) and press Shift-E, then pull the string you see attached to the mouse until the edges are as sharp as you want them. They will turn pinkish/purple as the crease gets sharper. You can adjust this at any time by pressing Shift-E again and relaxing the string with the mouse.

It's best to have the subdivision surface modifier on when you do this, so you can see how much the edges are being sharpened. You can get some really nice rounded edges this way.